# amazon_es output plugin installation error on an ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to install [this](https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es) plugin on my amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance. Normal installation using `bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-amazon_es` gives me error :

> Error Bundler::InstallError, retrying 1/10 An error occurred while
>   installing faraday_middleware (0.10.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install faraday_middleware -v '0.10.0'` succeeds
>   before bundling

So I tried cloning the repository and build the plugin using `gem build logstash-output-amazon_es.gemspec`. This succeeded :

`sudo bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-amazon_es-0.3.gem`

> Validating logstash-output-amazon_es-0.3.gem 
>   Installing logstash-output-amazon_es 
>   Installation successful

But when I do a `configtest` on my logstash configuration file, it throws me an error :

> The given configuration is invalid. Reason: Couldn't find any output
>   plugin named 'amazon_es'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load
>   the amazon_es output plugin resulted in this error: no such file to
>   load -- logstash/outputs/amazon_es {:level=>:fatal}

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm fighting the same error. Let me know if you find a solution!

Answer (score 4):

I installed the `logstash-output-amazon-es` plugin successfully. Here are the commands that worked:

```
cd /usr/share/logstash
sudo bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-amazon_es
```